# Saving slope rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, save, qgs

I've been creating maps from DEM data, then shading the slopes to identify hiking routes. Each time I close a project, the slope rasters disappear. How can I save slope rasters?

Comment: Right click your raster in the legend panel and choose export -> save as. Or choose a file output instead of a temporary one before running the processing tool.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to pre-select "save automatically", to avoid nominating save locations and file names each time?

Comment: QGIS warns you if you close the program and you have any unsafed layer (turn the warning on if not the case). Always read warning messages to be sure not to miss anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automatically name and save each slope raster file as it is created, in the slope window click "Run as Batch Process":

1. Underneath "Elevation layer", click "Autofill" and "Select from Open Layers", and make your selection.
2. Underneath "Slope", click the three dots, choose a save folder then enter a filename prefix like `SLOPE_`.
3. When prompted with autofill options, choose "Fill with parameter values" to automatically append the source name to `SLOPE_`.
4. Tick "Load layers on completion", then "Run".

Answer (score 3):

In general the trick is to save any temporary or memory layers before closing QGis. If like me you often forget to do this there is a plugin called [Memory Layer Saver](http://github.com/ccrook/QGIS-MemoryLayerSaver-Plugin) which does it for you.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'm looking for, but unfortunately the plugin is not functioning as I'd hoped. Installed it, closed and re-opened QGIS, tried adding a slope analysis and closing and re-opening the project, but it vanished. Did I miss a step?

Comment: may be it isn't a memory layer?